# QGIS, faulty Zonal Statistics calculations in case of empty polygons

Tags: qgis

I run QGIS 2.10 on a 64-bit Debian system and am currently trying to do some basic raster vector statistics.
However, I found that when applying the Zonal Statistics plugin, I end up with completely wrong values (instead of NULL) in case a zone does not have any raster cells within its boundaries. Apart from this, the calculations appear to be accurate.
Surfing SE for this error doesn't provide me with much insight except for knowing that the Zonal Statistics plugin seems to have a bit of an error history.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

In the meantime, I'll try my best using GRASS and SAGA...

After giving the original data a thorough inspection (there was no initial reason to be sceptical about its quality since it's supposedly official data), invalid geometries might be the problem. I'll double-check by drawing all polygons anew and get back to this later.

Using clean vector data didn't change anything. Thus, here's the bug report: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13081

Comment: Have you checked for reported bugs? Please report if there is no bug ticket for this error yet.

Comment: Yes, I have. If the problem persists, I'll report it.

Comment: Bug report added.